# Density of triple primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

The conjectural density of twin primes is $\frac {c\cdot n}{(\log n)^2}$ at a $c>0$.

Consider integers of form $p,p+1=2^tq,p+2=r$ where $p,q,r$ are primes and $t\geq1$ holds.

1. Is there any reason to believe there are infinite of them at a given $t\geq1$? Is there a conjectural density for such triples at a given $t$?
2. Is there any reason to believe there are infinite of them with $t$ not fixed? Is there a conjectural density for such triples with $t$ not fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your questions (more precisely their affirmative answers) are special cases of the generalized Hardy-Littlewood conjecture. You can read about this conjecture in [Linear equations in primes](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606088). See especially Conjecture 1.4 on Page 5 and the subsequent remarks on Page 6.

Comment: interesting....

Comment: @Turbo: Thank you. I think your "accept" was the quickest one for me on MathOverflow so far. Well under a minute!

Comment: @GHfromMO I believe it is relevant with his nickname ^^